# How to write a portable constexpr std::copysign()?

Tags: c++, math, nan, constexpr

In particular, it must work with NaNs as `std::copysign` does. Similarly, I need a constexpr `std::signbit`.

```
constexpr double copysign(double mag, double sgn)
{
    // how?
}

constexpr bool signbit(double arg)
{
    // how?
}

// produce the two types of NaNs
constexpr double nan_pos = copysign(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(), +1);
constexpr double nan_neg = copysign(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(), -1);

// must pass the checks
static_assert(signbit(nan_pos) == false);
static_assert(signbit(nan_neg) == true);
```

The story behind is that I need two types of NaNs at compile time, as well as ways to distinguish between them. The most straightforward way I can think of is to manipulate the sign bit of the NaNs. It does work at run time; now I just want to move some computations to compile time, and this is the last hurdle.

*Notes: at the moment, I'm relying on GCC, as it has built-in versions of these functions and they are indeed `constexpr`, which is nice. But I want my codebase to compile on Clang and perhaps other compilers too.*

Comment: Are positive and negative infinity valid values for you?  If not, you could use those as your two sentinel values.

Comment: We've considered infinity, but they don't fit in well in the codebase. It has to be NaN, unfortunately.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::nan("1")` and `std::nan("2")`?

Comment: @Eljay Those aren't constexpr.

Comment: @NathanOliver • Well... that's unfortunate!

Comment: Not a full solution, but a general direction: Would you be able to work with intermediate structs? Something like https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TrvKonqEz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `__builtin...` is not really *portable*, but works in compilers that mentioned as target. `__builtin_copysign` is contexpr, but `__builtin_signbit` is apparently not on clang, so doing `signbit` with `__builtin_copysign`:

```
#include <limits>

constexpr double copysign(double mag, double sgn)
{
    return __builtin_copysign(mag, sgn);
}

constexpr bool signbit(double arg)
{
    return __builtin_copysign(1, arg) <  0;
}

// produce the two types of NaNs
constexpr double nan_pos = copysign(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(), +1);
constexpr double nan_neg = copysign(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(), -1);

// must pass the checks
static_assert(signbit(nan_pos) == false);
static_assert(signbit(nan_neg) == true);

int main() {}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8Wafaj4a4

Answer (score 2):

[P0533](http://wg21.link/p0533): constexpr for `<cmath>` and `<cstdlib>` is now accepted.

Starting in C++23 you can just use `std::copysign` and `std::syncbit`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `std::bit_cast`, you can manipulate floating point types cast to integer types. The portability is limited to the representation of `double`, but if you can assume the IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format, cast to uint64_t and using sign bit should work.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `std::bit_cast` is only available in [tag:c++20], which may not necessarily be available depending on the organization and codebase.

Comment: Thanks for bringing `bit_cast` up! At the moment we are using GCC 9 and Clang 9; too bad we can't use `bit_cast` yet. Will keep it in mind though.